# What sort of intonation should I have when using だろう/でしょう?

Tags: pronunciation

Pretty straightforward question. When using だろう or でしょう as a way to express unassertiveness on my sentence (i.e., "it seems", "it looks like"), what intonation should I use? Does it follow a pattern similar to a question (か) or a affirmation (だ)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the ***falling*** intonation as you would with affirmation.  That is to say, you go:

「だろう{LHL}」 and 「でしょう{LHHL}」

When used at the end of yes/no questions, they need to be pronounced with a ***rising*** intonation as in:

「だろう{LHH}」 and 「でしょう{LHHH}」